# Dlang - How to "install" libraries to my compilator?

Tags: xamarin, monodevelop, d, libraries

I had a lot expirience of programming in C++, and then when I wanted to take advantage of some library I just usually copy .lib / .dll and .h .cpp files to the appropriate directories of compiler (to install them). Then I had to add in the program - header like #include "something.hpp" and in compiler add a command to include the library.

Now I want to start programming in D and unfortunately I can not reproduce the above procedure. Can someone tell me how to do it with DMD compiler? As IDE I'm using Mono-D (Xamarin).

For example, I was trying to install the library called "vibe" and then "mysql-lite" but.. yeah in D we dont have any header files and etc.

I also failed to make "DUB"  cooperate with "Mono-D"

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Thank you in advance for your reply, I really want to learn that language!

Comment: `dub` is D's package manager; read on how to use it first. Make a `dub.json` file for your project (ex. with `dub init`), edit the file to include your packages, the build with `dub build` (or open `dub.json` in Mono-D).

Comment: Woo! This roughly works. Everything is like you said.

I prepare project like: dub init mysql vibe-d mysql-lited
This create project files, Next i opened .dub/mysql.json as project file in Mono-D, then add files that DUB download/prepared for me. 

Hm.. I currently have a mess with all those files, but I will play with this so - it works :D

Thank you very much @ColonelThirtyTwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i played with above method, but unfortunately in this case i can't save my project(and workspace) and every time when i open up my "project" i need to add files generated by DUB...

So i came up with the following solution:

1) First - we need to create new clean D project in Mono-D/Xamarin, then in some temporary folder we need to create DUB project with all dependencies like:
dub init  .  Note that Mono-D and DUB project should have the same name.

2) Next step is copying files(and folders) generated by DUB to folder that contains our Mono-D project (dub.sdl; source/app.d) and add those files to project via Mono-D.

3)Then you only need to configure Mono-D. First go to "Project"->" Options" -> [Build Head] "Own commands". Choose "Build" and as command set "dub build". Next go to "Project"->" Options" -> [Run Head] "Own commands". Choose "Run" and as command set "${ProjectName}.exe"

And that is all, but if you want to use Mono-D hint system (prediction):

4) You need to add .d source files to compiler - just copy them (source files of dependencies that DUB downloaded) to src/phobos/etc/ folder (for DMD compiler)

Now everything whizzes beautiful!

And if you want to add some dependencies later you need to add it to dub.sdl file.

Thank you for guidance and tips!